# Помогите разобраться с .htaccess - что делают эти выражения

Tags: .htaccess

Файл .htaccess:

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !site\.ua$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Помогите разобраться что эти строки делают. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В общих чертах - добавляет www. перед адресом.

`RewriteRule` устраивает редирект (R=301, код редиректа) на адрес http://www."к чему обратились"/путь/...

Делает он это не во всех случаях, а по условиям, описанным в `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !site\.ua$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}
```

Это условия на несовпадение переменной HTTP_HOST шаблонам: не начинается с m, не начинается с www, не являается site.ua, не IP-адрес.

А также:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog/
```

не был запрошен путь /blog/

Наконец, самое хитрое:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)
```

Скобки в регулярке запоминают выражение - и полностью запоминают HTTP_HOST в переменную %1.

После чего

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

подставляет захваченную %1 в предыдущем RewriteCond, подставляют $1 из пути, сервер возвращает редирект 301 на новый адрес, и обработка путей прекращается.

[Документация по mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)